# How to attach Chrome developer tools to the same window?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying out the developer tools on Chrome for Mac OS and I'm finding a huge annoyance. I don't see an obvious method to make the tools window attach to the bottom of the page I'm inspecting like in Firebug and Safari

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to get a developer window and then use the bottom left button.

[image]

To be clear: I do not own a MAC so I can't test this **but** it does work on Chrome/Linux for sure.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asking about Mac OS. In Chrome for Mac, opt-command-j is what you use to open the window. But there's no visible option to attach it.

Comment: No luck here either on Mac OS.  Thanks for the short cut though!

Comment: is the extension sub-system enabled? there is an option on the command-line to enable them.

Comment: got outdated for now! answer from @overZellis is working currently!

Answer (score 26):

I was able to dock the developer tools into the same window by clicking on the stoplight icon in the top right of the developer tools window.
You can then click on the appropriate icon to either open in a separate window, doc the developer tools on the bottom of the same window, or doc the developer tools on the right side of the same window.

[image: Location of tool window docking options]

Comment: Looks like I don't have enough points to embed images in my comments, but if you click on the image link, I've used Skitch to point out where these icons are within the Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot pointing to where the docking options live, I was looking everywhere. :+1: For some reason they aren't available for this instance of the window.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is a little bit old but I've just found out you just need to click in the most left icon in the bottom of developer tools window.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could attach a photo.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing (Chrome 32 for the mac), the icon you're looking for is on the top right of the developer tools. It looks like a window pane.

Depending on your chrome theme, this button may blend in with the background, but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

The Way to attach the Developer's tool to the same tab is simple..  Follow these Steps:-

1. You open developer Tool By pressing ctrl+shift+i or Cntrl+shift+J  (supposing it opened in a new window)
2. In the developer Tool Window, On the top right corner you'll see three vertical dots. click it, and on the top you'll see "Dock Side" option. From this option you can change the setting..  i.e. to open the developer tool in the same webpage..
   Cheers!

Comment: This is a 10 year old question with an already accepted answer. If you think the answer has changed, you should be clear in your answer which specific version this is now relevant in.

Answer (score 0):

1. To Start:
   Mac: Cmd + option + j
   Windows: ctrl + shift + J
2. Click on left side options, as highlighted
   [image]